# How to convert docker-compose to kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

I have an example project with nginx, php-fpm, mysql:
https://gitlab.com/x-team-blog/docker-compose-php

**This is the docker-compose file:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

  database:
    build:
      context: ./database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
    volumes:
      - ./database/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql
```

I'd like to use Kubernetes in Google Cloud and for this I have created several files:

**Persistent Volume database-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml:**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: database-claim0
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 400Mi
```

Also I created **secrets**:

```
kubectl create secret generic mysql --from-literal=MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb --from-literal=MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret --from-literal=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker --from-literal=MYSQL_USER=myuser
```

Then I created a **service**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
  labels:
    app: database
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: database
```

And now I'd like to create database-deployment.yaml, but I don't know what I have to write in the volumeMounts section for copy sql file like docker-compose:

```
- ./database/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql
```

**database-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: database
  labels:
    app: database
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: database
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: database
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mariadb
          name: database
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql
                  key: MYSQL_DATABASE
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql
                  key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql
                  key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql
                  key: MYSQL_USER
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: database
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: database-claim0
```

UPD:
My mistake. I did not push images first.

Answer (score 3):

Use [kompose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose)

```
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-service.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "database-deployment.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "database-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-deployment.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-claim1-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-claim2-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-claim3-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "php-fpm-deployment.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "php-fpm-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but then I have to use the Kompose, I get error, like:
kompose WARN Volume mount on the host isn't supported - ignoring path on the host. And many other errors due to which pods do not work.

Kompose version:
1.17.0 (a74acad)

Comment: I just went through this. kompose is the best option. Then use those files to compile a sane service and deploy yaml.

Comment: I try to use kompose and Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine and database pod doesn't work. Pod error. Maybe I do not have enough knowledge about the features of kubernetes. A command "docker-compose up" is works fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is an Online tool [here](https://8gwifi.org/kube1.jsp) which help generating most of the Docker compose file converted to the Kubernetes Resources
[image]